# Does Google's browser size statistic include mobile devices?

Tags: browsers, google, html

I'm trying to figure out a perfect size for my HTML5 game area, with the help of [Google's browser size statistics](http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/), but it seems as I need to restrict myself to such small dimensions because, apparently, people either have very small monitors, or Google includes mobile devices to their statistics. If Google does that, I'll happily choose better (bigger) dimensions, but what should those be, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason for the extremely low resolutions seen there seems to be that [the overlay image](http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/static/2009-11-18-day_google_com_100_donate_example.png) is about 3 years old (the filename says `2009-11-18`, the data itself may be even older) - times where full-hd screens weren't as widespread as today and the most used resolution was `1024x768`.

this doesn't seem to be live and up to date statistics, so they're pretty useless nowadays (regardless of whether mobile devices are included (which is what i assume) or not) - the data is just too old.